# Excel: How to reference every cell in array in spreadsheet based on upper left most cell primary key?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel spreadsheets.

One spreadsheet contains hundreds of 10 row, 2 column "mini-spreadsheets" that each have a unique identifier in the upper left most cell.

On my second spreadsheet, my goal is to create a presentable spreadsheet that I can print out to show people in a way that is readable. I want to reference every cell in these "mini-spreadsheets", as they relate to the upper leftern most cell and present accordingly.

What can I do to fulfill this need?

Comment: What have your tried so far. We are not a free coding service. Also, since I've seen a similar request yesterday it makes me feel like this is homework. As such I suggest this be marked as closed.

Comment: With the above in mind; do look into `OFFSET()` mainly (with a caluclation for the reference point, the identifier cell, primary key), possibly also `TRANSPOSE()` to create a list of those identifiers that can be used as argument to a drop down list to select them from.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(C4, 'Song List'!$A$2:$B$552,2,FALSE)

Comment: =INDEX('Service History'!$A$1:$B$100,MATCH(A1, 'Service History'!$A$12:$A$100,4),1)

Comment: @MatthewB I would strongly recommend you delete your last comment, I believe it violates the SU TOS.  SuperUser is a volunteer community of people willing to put a few minutes here and there helping people with specific questions.  Requesters that aren't willing to invest 10-15 minutes to create an example problem, a sample of the desired output, and a more detailed description of what they have tried and why what they've tried isn't working are usually downvoted, and their questions are often removed.  I assure you that leaving your "smart guy" comment up will ensure the question is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your data is in `Sheet1` columns `A:B`.  Your first set starts in `A1:B10`, the second set in `A12:B21` and so on.  This leaves a blank row between each set.

You'll need a sequence to return the start row of each set:
`=SEQUENCE(4,,1,11)`
This will be good for 4 sets - change the 4 to however many sets you've got, or devise a formula that will count for you.

Combine SEQUENCE with INDEX to return the unique identifier for each set.
`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,SEQUENCE(4,,1,11))`
This will return the values in cells A1, A12, A23 & A34.

Create a named range that references the above spilled formula (my formula is in cell D2):
`=Sheet1!$D$2#`.
I've called it *MyLookUp*.

Create a List data validation that references MyLookUp.  This will give you a drop-down of your unique identifiers.  I've placed this in cell F2.

Finally, create a formula to return your dataset:
`=INDEX($A:$A,XMATCH($F$2,$A:$A)):INDEX($B:$B,XMATCH($F$2,$A:$A)+9)`

[image]